# Apache Ignite Failover functionality

Tags: memcached, ignite

I have set apache ignite on a Cluster of nodes and sent some job to some server node to run. When connection to that server node was lost I need to somehow store the result of that node locally (either via binary file or via some other way). Then when the connection with that node is established again push back the stored results to some Database server.
I'm working under .Net platform.
I can use 
          EventType.EVT_CLIENT_NODE_DISCONNECTED
          EventType.EVT_CLIENT_NODE_RECONNECTED

these events and inside of their functions to implement the 'storing locally' and 'pushing to the DB server' functionality but I wanted to find some ready solution.
Is there any ready tool with the functionality I mentioned to just take and use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Checkpointing](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/checkpointing). I'm not sure this is exactly the same as you described (mainly because it will save the intermidiate state on server side), but I think it can be quite helpful.

Comment: Checkpointing seems to be the answer, but there is no support for it yet in Ignite.NET. It is planned though: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4427

Comment: Thanks a lot Valentin. I have already found it but apache ignite has only Java version for ckeckpointing.

Comment: For .Net they have opened a new ticket and will implement it soon.